# When a ComboBox value is selected, output particular text (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox

I'm creating a decision interface for clinical support with numerous amounts of combo boxes with boolean values 'Yes|No". However I want it so if the user choses either yes or no, a button can be clicked at the bottom and then another windows form appears and says whether they have cancer or not.

For example, if the user clicks 'yes' in the comboBox and then clicks the 'submit' button, another form will appear and the text box will say whether they have cancer or not. Would anyone be able to supply an example of how this would work? I have the form with the combo boxes, a button that links to another form, and a textbox inside the second form....but I can't get the information between the two forms.

The code I have at the moment is

```
Private Sub submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submit.Click 
    If (RectalBleeding.SelectedItem = "Yes") Then Outcome.OutcomeBox.Text = "you have cancer" End If Outcome.Show()
End Sub
```

Particular combo box im trying to link is called 'RectalBleeding'. The button on the decision interface form is called 'submit' the second form is called 'outcome'. The box inside outcome is called 'outcomeBox' I want it so that if 'Yes' was chosen in the comboBox, the user clicks 'submit' second form appears and in the text box it says "you have cancer"

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant code you have in your question.

Comment: Did you really need to use a disturbing cancer diagnosis to show an example of your problem? A simple "Do you like ice cream?" then show "Me too" would suffice.

Comment: It's what I'm designing, a cancer interface to aid clinical support, should have said that beforehand.

Comment: I like that a combobox can be so definitive.  No need for Xrays or pesky MRIs, just go see a ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

You can use public properties and constructors to pass values between two forms. Below is some code that uses these tools for your purpose.

Here is the code for the main form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private frm As Outcome
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddDecision()
    End Sub
    Private Sub AddDecision()
        RectalBleeding.Items.Add("Yes")
        RectalBleeding.Items.Add("No")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
        If RectalBleeding.Text = "Yes" Then
            frm = New Outcome("You have cancer")
        Else
            frm = New Outcome("You don't have cancer")
        End If
        frm.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

and here for the outcome form

```
Public Class Outcome
    Private _Decision As String
    Public Property Decision() As String
        Get
            Return _Decision
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Decision = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Sub Outcome_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillTextBox()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal results As String)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.Decision = results
    End Sub
    Private Sub FillTextBox()
        outcomeBox.Text = Me.Decision
    End Sub
End Class
```